# XPages inputTextArea is not editable

Tags: xpages

When i use multiLine editbox (shown in FIRST ONE) It cannot be editable If the document is in editMode. 
But SECOND ONE is editable. My point is if use formula at the value of inputTextArea It can not be editable. 
I could not find what it is that i missed?

FIRST ONE:

```
<xp:inputTextarea id="muvName" rows="2" cols="70"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@Implode(document1.getItemValue("muvName"))+ @NewLine() + "C/o";}]]></xp:this.value></xp:inputTextarea>
```

SECOND ONE:

```
<xp:inputTextarea id="muvName" rows="2" cols="70" value="#{document1.muvName}">
</xp:inputTextarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the property `defaultValue` to define a default value:

```xml
   <xp:inputTextarea
        id="muvName"
        rows="2"
        cols="70"
        value="#{document1.muvName}">
        <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            @Implode(document1.muvName)+ @NewLine() + "C/o"
        }]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
    </xp:inputTextarea>
```

and use property `value` for binding a document's item (or a scope variable) to the editable field. `value` has to be an object to which XPage can write the submitted content to.

In your first example you calculate a string and it's impossible to write something back to a calculated string. That's why the field is read only.

*Update:*

If you want to correct document field's value before editing then use a custom converter instead:

```xml
<xp:inputTextarea
    id="muvName"
    rows="10"
    cols="70"
    value="#{document1.muvName}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:customConverter
            getAsObject="#{javascript:value}">
            <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                if (!value.endsWith("C/o")) {
                    value += @NewLine() + "C/o";
                }
                value
            }]]></xp:this.getAsString>
        </xp:customConverter>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: When I tried It worked but The string ""C/o" could not be added :(
It only shows value of field without "Newline" and without "C/o" :(

Comment: If you want to manipulate the value there are a few options, ranging from simple but hacks to more complex but standard for XPages/JSF. 1) Bind the field to a scoped variable instead of document1, then set the scoped variable on load and have a hiddenInput that adds a newline and "C/o" if missing. 2) Add the newline and "C/o" in your save logic. 3) Use a custom converter to add whatever is required. 4) If you use a bean behind the fields that wraps DominoDocument, manipulate in a custom setter. (There may be other options too.)